# GraphiQL subscriptions working with subscriptions-transport-ws 0.7.3, but not 0.8.2

Tags: subscriptions, graphiql

I have a nodejs GraphQL app running with the following

```
"graphql": "^0.10.5",
"graphql-errors": "^2.1.0",
"graphql-server-core": "^1.1.0",
"graphql-server-express": "^1.1.0",
"graphql-server-module-graphiql": "^1.1.0",
"graphql-subscriptions": "^0.4.4",
"graphql-tools": "^1.2.1",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.7.3",
```

Using this configuration, I can define a subscription in graphiql and watch the result appear in the output pane replacing the boilerplate message `"Your subscription data will appear here after server publication!"`.

If I switch to the latest version of susbcriptions-transport-ws i.e.

```
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.8.2",
```

this no longer works; the boilerplate message does not appear in the output pane and instead I get the cryptic `[object] [object]` message.

I've not been able to find any statement about version compatibility between graphiql and subscriptions-transport-ws; does anyone know if this version mix is supported?

Comment: Have you raised an issue on the `susbcriptions-transport-ws` repo and/or tried bisecting to find which commit changed this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the `[Object Object]` error in graphiql by reverting to these versions of following libraries in package.json:

    `"graphql-subscriptions": "^0.4.3",
    "graphql-tools": "^1.0.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "0.7.3",`